# Migrating Salesforce CMS Content

Tags: community

we are using Salesforce CMS to expose content within our Communities. We're gathering in the CMS e.g. blog content and footers, so some of the content will be designed on the sandbox level. Is there any convenient way to deploy/export/load content between sandboxes and/or production? I know that Knowledge articles were stored within custom objects available for query, but I didn't find anything like this for the CMS. All objects related with CMS are not available for query.

Comment: Were you able to find anything?

Comment: Not at all, unfortunately. All of our work is deployed using manual procedures, this is terrible.